# Create additional pages in jsPDF

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

I am using jsPDF and Angularjs and am trying to create additional pages.  I want to add a new page when the current page is filled.

**Code:**

```
$scope.goPdf = function ()
{
    console.log('Create PDF');

    $('#pdf').css('background', '#fff');
    $('#pdf').css('font-size', '20px');
    $(".sleep").attr("hidden", true);

    html2canvas($("#pdf"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            console.log(canvas.clientHeight)
            return false;
            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 15, 10, 180, 140);
           // pdf.setFontSize(40);
            pdf.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            pdf.addPage();
            pdf.save('namePdf' + '.pdf');
            $(".sleep").attr("hidden", false);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

addPage has two parameters that you need to fill in.
addPage(format, orientation)
example

> addPage('letter', 'p')

You can view more of its documentation here:
http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/